# Python code does not write anything inside the file

Tags: python, file, discord, discord.py, bots

I have and problem with my code. It is a part of mine command for discored bot, but it fails to write anything inside file with no error

```py
item = "Scrap Metal"
price = 0.56 #per gram
cost = grams * price
cost = round(cost)
human = random.randrange(1, 3)
if human == 1:
    human = "Chinese web store"
elif human == 2:
    human = "TechKnow scrap yard"
elif human == 3:
    human= "Random guy on the street"
embed = discord.Embed(title="You went mining!", description=f"You have found **{grams}g** of **{item}**.\n\nYou sold it to **{human}** for **{cost}**!", color=0x00ffee)
await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
try:
    f = open(f"./all/users/{ctx.author.id}/balance.txt", "r+")
    a = f.read()
    int(a)
    f.close()
except:
    a = 0

i = cost
i = a + i
str(i)

f = open(f"./all/users/{ctx.author.id}/balance.txt", "w+")
f.seek(0)
f.write(i)
f.close()
```

Thank you for your help upfront

Comment: The result of `str(i)` is not being assigned to anything. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: You don't need `f.seek(0)`. When you open a file in `w` mode, the file is emptied and the file position is set to the beginning. There's also no need for the `+` in the open mode, since you're not reading from the file.

Comment: `int(a)` isn't being saved anywhere. I think you want `a = int(a)`

Comment: Where do you set `grams`?

Comment: If you're not getting any errors, are you sure the code is running? It definitely has statements that should get errors.

Comment: @Barmar at the start of the command that I did not shared here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains statements that should throw an errors. Here are at least some of them:

1. `str(i)` should be replaced to `i = str(i)`. Without this, the script tries to write `i` as a number to the file and throws `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int`
2. `int(a)` should be replaced by `a = int(a)` when you read the file. Otherwise `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str` will be thrown when you try `i = a + i`

If you don't get any errors, then make sure that this code runs at all.

Comment: The OP is not having an error, but an empty file, "with no error".

Comment: This worked for me. I don't know why I am not getting any errors. I had a problem with no error message before. It's somehow associated with my 3k line code, which I don't want to manually check. Ty for answering.